# Ant build tool failure

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, ant, tomcat6

I am getting the following failure while I was trying to run my project using `Eclipse Juno IDE`.

Can anyone help me over to fix this  Message in `Eclipse Juno Console`:

```
Buildfile: C:\online1\OnlineQuestion\build.xml build: build: deploy:      
[copy] Copying 103 files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\Tomcat6.0\webapps\OnlineTestEngine  BUILD FAILED     
C:\online1\OnlineQuestion\build.xml:46: Failed to copy 
C:\online1\OnlineQuestion\war\1Result.jsp to C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\Tomcat6.0\webapps\OnlineTestEngine\1Result.jsp 
due to failed to create the parent directory for C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\OnlineTestEngine\1Result.jsp  
Total time: 827 millisecond
```

Comment: `Failed to copy` <-- seems pretty obvious what is happening here

Comment: `due to failed to create the parent directory`

Comment: @BharathNatarajan Anyone help but anybody here?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write files or create folders in `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`, you need to run as Adminstrator, otherwise write access is denied.

There are three potential solutions:

1. Run ant from a cmd prompt that is started as administrator or attempt to run Eclipse as administrator
2. Install Tomcat in a location outside of `Program Files` so no elevated privileges are required to deploy the files from your build script
3. Edit your Tomcat `server.xml` and change the appBase to somewhere you have write permission, e.g. `<Host name="localhost" appBase="C:\Users\me\webapps" ...`

Comment: 3. Edit your Tomcat `server.xml` and change the `appBase` to somewhere you have write permission, e.g. `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="C:\Users\me\webapps" ...`

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks, I don't do much with Tomcat; I added your comment in my answer

Comment: Thanks Mr.Mark for your kind reply. I tried it now and its working...Thankyou.